# Как распаковать архив из ресурсов одним действием?

Tags: c#

Есть программка. В нее зашит Zip архив. Сначала у меня происходит извлечение ресурса во временную папку

```
File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, (byte[])Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(res.Key));
```

Затем уже архив распаковывается

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(Path.Combine(TempDir, fileName), libsPath);
```

Оба процесса занимают по 10 секунд. А как можно сразу распаковать архив из ресурсов, не имея файл на диске? Если, конечно, это возможно.

Comment: Неужели вам оба ответа не нравятся, может поставить галочку на одном из двух? Или вы хотите решение полностью на потоках?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно, например.
Для работы с Zip архивами использую библиотеку [SharpZipLib](https://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/). Ставится легко и быстро через Nuget.

Взяв [отсюда](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples#anchorUnpackFull) пример по распаковке Zip-архива, написал такую функцию(чуточку переделал ее)

```
public static void ExtractZipFile(Stream inputStream, string password, string outFolder)
        {
            ZipFile zf = null;
            try
            {
                zf = new ZipFile(inputStream);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                {
                    zf.Password = password;     // AES encrypted entries are handled automatically
                }
                foreach (ZipEntry zipEntry in zf)
                {
                    if (!zipEntry.IsFile)
                    {
                        continue;           // Ignore directories
                    }
                    String entryFileName = zipEntry.Name;
                    // to remove the folder from the entry:- entryFileName = Path.GetFileName(entryFileName);
                    // Optionally match entrynames against a selection list here to skip as desired.
                    // The unpacked length is available in the zipEntry.Size property.

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];     // 4K is optimum
                    Stream zipStream = zf.GetInputStream(zipEntry);

                    // Manipulate the output filename here as desired.
                    String fullZipToPath = Path.Combine(outFolder, entryFileName);
                    string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullZipToPath);
                    if (directoryName.Length > 0)
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);

                    // Unzip file in buffered chunks. This is just as fast as unpacking to a buffer the full size
                    // of the file, but does not waste memory.
                    // The "using" will close the stream even if an exception occurs.
                    using (FileStream streamWriter = File.Create(fullZipToPath))
                    {
                        StreamUtils.Copy(zipStream, streamWriter, buffer);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (zf != null)
                {
                    zf.IsStreamOwner = true; // Makes close also shut the underlying stream
                    zf.Close(); // Ensure we release resources
                }
            }
        }
```

Теперь, создав из массива байт поток, можно вызвать эту функцию следующим образом

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
stream.Position = 0;
ExtractZipFile(stream, "", @"DestFolder");
```

Comment: Все это есть в System.IO.Compression. Не вижу смысла в использовании сторонних библиотек. Плюсанул все равно

Comment: хорошо, что есть :). Главная идея. Использую стороннюю библиотеку, в связи с тем, что нужна работа с другими типами архивов

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.IO;

var za = ZipFile.Open(@"C:\Temp\test.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Read);
var e = za.Entries.First();
using(var s = e.Open()) {
   // ...
}
```

если zip в виде byte[], то так

```
byte[] bytes = ...
var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
var za = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Read));
// ...
```

Comment: Вопрос внимательнее прочитайте

Comment: _"Вопрос внимательнее прочитайте"_ -- почитал. у вас там byte[]. его просто можно поместить в memorystream и передать в ziparchive. обновил ответ.

Comment: Конечно можно. Тем не менее в вашем ответе фигурирует ZipFile, а не ZipArchive и обращение по имени файла идет.

Comment: @iRumba _"фигурирует ZipFile, а не ZipArchive"_ -- добавил `new ZipArchive(ms,...`