# Как считать метаданные с .slx файла используя C#?

Tags: c#, matlab

Когда я создаю Sumulink model (.slx) в MATLAB с помощью следующего MATLAB кода  записываю в него свои данные.

`h = load_system(pathToFile);
set_param(h, 'Metadata', properties)`

.slx файл имеет zip формат, поэтому мне удалось узнать что мои данные пишутся в файл .mxarray.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как я могу вытянуть мои данные с .slx или .mxarray файла использую C#? Или как по другому записать кастомные свойства в .slx файл чтобы потом их достать в С# проекте?

Comment: Максимум чем можно тут помочь - дать пример распаковки zip. Вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/677294/17974 пример как забрать зазипованый поток из файла `word/document.xml` который в зипе.

Comment: У меня был похожий вариант записать  свой xml файл в zip, но проблема в том что когда я буду  это  делать в MATLAB коде файл .slx может выполняться и соответственно будет ошибка.

Comment: это не запись. это чтение docx, который так же представляет собой zip формат. Вы ведь написали "как считать". Надо знать какой из архивов брать. Найти начало архива (двоичный Deflate), натравить туда DeflateStream сказать ему фас `Read` - и вы прочтетё "метаданные". Без деталей более конкретно ответить не получится. Конкретизируйте, покажите сигнатуры дампы. Посмотрите на примеры сигнатур в дампе zip https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/681886/17974

Comment: Есть ещё класс `ZipFile`, если вы новичёк, то вам через ZipFile будет проще. Он не поддерживает потоки, тут есть примеры https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478971/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%85%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc/478979 . ZipFile есть на msdn. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files